# mvc Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: model-view-controller, html-helper

I have a question here about html.textboxfor

I knew that we can use Html.TextBoxFor to restrict the size of the user input

Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmployerNumber, new {size=3})

But can we configure it to take numeric value only ?

I try to get Html.ValidationMessageFor to throw error when input value is not numeric.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

a textbox accepts text so its not really capable of being limited just to numbers.  the best way to do what you want to do is have a model set up that only accepts numeric values and then use client side validation to alert the user that only numeric values are acceptable.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I am aware of that, but because the business rule that I am implementing stops me from using the strong typed form.

Comment: well otherwise you could always use regular expressions in javascript.  set a listener to the onKeyUp event in javascript, have it tied to the textbox and simply use a RegEx (/^[0-9]+$/) to restrict the input to being only numbers.